# Wireshark Capture Filter

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ping, wireshark, icmp

I am new to wireshark and I am trying to capture an ICMP packet over 802.11g, I am using windows and pingplotter. The issue is that on wireshark capture I am not getting any ICMP packets no matter how much I try.
I know there has to be something I messed up in the settings because HTTP and any ipv4 are not being captured/or displayed but I cannot figure out how to fix this.
Thank you for any hints

@Garrett yes I made sure what interface I am using and its on the same computer, @Daniel B the only way to filter that I know of is the display filter and it is cleared, eventually I got tired and downloaded pinglotter and wireshark on another PC and it worked fine I could see ICMP packets, guess we'll never know what the problem was! Thank you anyway

Comment: Simply capture without a filter. You can always filter in the results window afterwards. If you don't have to sift through extreme amounts of traffic, that's acceptable.

Comment: Are you sure that this traffic is going through your 802.11g NIC? Is the traffic being generated from the computer with this NIC installed or another computer?